# How can I check if a matrix is an element of a list of matrices? in R

Tags: r, vector, matrix, matching, element

I'm pretty new to programming in R.

I have a matrix of numbers `mat`,  as well as a list of matrices `matlist`. I want to check if the matrix `mat` matches with (i.e., is identical to) any element of `matlist`. I tried the `%in%` method but this doesn't give me the output I hope for.

Here's something like my code.

```
mat <- rbind(c(0,1),
             c(1,0))
mat2 <- rbind(c(1,1),
              c(1,0))
matlist <- vector(mode="list", 2)
matlist[[1]] <- mat
matlist[[2]] <- mat2
```

If I then try `mat %in% matlist` I get:
    `FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

I'm looking for an expression like this which will evaluate to `TRUE`.

This seems like it should be really simple but I can't find an answer!

Comment: Note that you can also create that list with `matlist <- list(mat, mat2)`, or, if you want elements named, then for example `matlist <- list(m1=mat, m2=mat2)`.

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like:

`sapply(matlist,function(x) identical(x,mat))`, or as @jbaums mentions below: `sapply(matlist,identical,mat)`

Or build yourself a custom function to check any matrix in any matrix list:

```
matrix_is_in <- function(my_mat, my_mat_list) {
      sapply(my_matlist, function(x) identical(x, my_mat))
}
```

Then try it out:

`matrix_is_in(mat,matlist)`

Comment: Or, more simply, `sapply(matlist, identical, mat)`.

Comment: Great! `sapply(matlist,identical,mat)` returns `TRUE FALSE` but I can just embed that in `any()` and I get exactly what I need. Thank you!